# How to enable plain text format for body in specific content type

Tags: 8, entities

I have one content type, where I want to restrict the body field to plain text only. In Drupal 7, there was an option to set the plain text format explicitly in field configuration; however in Drupal 8, there is no "plain text" option in the select box. I cannot change user permissions to text formats, because I want to have plain text for the administrator as well.

In Drupal 7:

[image]

In Drupal 8:

[image]

So please, how to force the plain text in body field? Do I have to create a new text format? If so, why such a nonsense (my desired text format already exists, but cannot be used)?

Thanks!

Comment: Does plain text exist as a text format? Are these screens from user 1? Do you have any custom code that might manipulate the options?

Comment: @Kevin yes, plain text format exists. These screens are from user 1 (administrator). No custom code. I suppose, that this has something to do with comment by plain text format in Drupal 8, which states `This format is shown when no other formats are available`. But again, I do not see any logic here for this behavior..

Comment: @JurajNemec, it should work, if you reset the text formats and permissions to default and use Allowed Formats to restrict the format to Plain Text in the field. See my answer

Comment: @JurajNemec Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the issue [Allow text field to enforce a specific text format](https://www.drupal.org/node/784672). You can use the patch from this issue or install the module [Allowed Formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_formats) which provides these options in the text field configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've got a good point. I don't know why the built in plain text format is disabled unless all other formats are deleted ... "This format is shown when no other formats are available."

I couldn't find an answer for it's disabled either.

So you have to create a new plain text format.

All you have to do is go to admin/config/content/formats. Then Add text format.  Then fill out the next screen and set Display any HTML as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 Just add new plain text format by giving the extra space between plain and text label it will create the new one for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with a hidden config option (not present in the GUI). You can set it from drush:

```
drush cset filter.settings always_show_fallback_choice TRUE
```